# Getting NullpointerException in JSF facesContext

Tags: jsf-2, junit4

I am getting null pointer exception in Junit when I am trying to test the method which contains facesContext (which is related to JSF back end bean).

context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet();

Here I am getting NullpointerExeotion.

How to avoid this exception in Junit.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test needs to run on server-side.
With the use of Cactus you could do that.
There is also another project JSFUnit but never test it.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply.Can you give any sample program or steps how to catcus framework.

Comment: Sorry, Cactus seems dead. take a look of Arquillan : http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html. I try to push a sample of code a soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..can you please help how to use arquillian framework to resolve above issue.